# Swift JSONDecoder throws an error during build

Tags: ios, json, swift

Hello I have a json file looking like this

```
}
"CYYZ": {
        "icao": "CYYZ",
        "iata": "YYZ",
        "name": "Lester B. Pearson International Airport",
        "city": "Toronto",
        "state": "Ontario",
        "country": "CA",
        "elevation": 569,
        "latitude": 43.6772003174,
        "longitude": -79.6305999756,
        "tz": "America\/Toronto"
    },
    "CYZD": {
        "icao": "CYZD",
        "iata": "YZD",
        "name": "Downsview Airport",
        "city": "Toronto",
        "state": "Ontario",
        "country": "CA",
        "elevation": 652,
        "latitude": 43.7425003052,
        "longitude": -79.4655990601,
        "tz": "America\/Toronto"
    },
    "CYZE": {
        "icao": "CYZE",
        "iata": "YZE",
        "name": "Gore Bay Manitoulin Airport",
        "city": "Gore Bay",
        "state": "Ontario",
        "country": "CA",
        "elevation": 635,
        "latitude": 45.8852996826,
        "longitude": -82.5678024292,
        "tz": "America\/Toronto"
    }
}
```

I make a struct like this

```
struct AirportData: Codable{
    let iata: String
    let name: String
    let longitude: Double
    let latitude: Double
}
```

and I wrote the following code to set up the url and make it a string then I use it to decode the json

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

//make url for file path
    guard let jsonURL = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).path(forResource: "airports", ofType: "json") else {
                return
            }
            //make url a string
            guard let jsonString = try? String(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath:jsonURL), encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
                return
            }
            
            var airports: AirportData?
            do{
                airports = try JSONDecoder().decode(AirportData.self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))
            }
            catch{
                print("error occured when decoding")
            }
            
            
            guard let results = airports else {
                return
            }
            
            print(results.iata)
                
            }
```

I keep getting "error occurred when decoding"

please help I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCfbrEeNkvo&t=302s) tutorial but not getting same results maybe my struct is wrong. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First your json is not correct, the first bracket should be "{" not "}".

Second, your data structure is not correct, use this:

```
struct AirportData: Codable {
    let icao, iata, name, city: String
    let state, country: String
    let elevation: Int
    let latitude, longitude: Double
    let tz: String
}

typealias Response = [String: AirportData]
```

Third, your `viewDidLoad` code is a mess. Use something like this to get your data:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var airports: [String:AirportData]?
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "airports", withExtension: "json") {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            airports = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
            print("\n---> airports: \(airports) \n")
        } catch {
            print("error occured when decoding: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes force unwrap is better than failing silently. If OP is sure that he has included that file in the bundle crashing if the file is not there will be much more helpful. `let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "airports", withExtension: "json")!`

Comment: yes you could do that, but in this case it is probably better to just put an `else {...}` and show an alert or something, than to crash the app completely.

Comment: Alert for the developer? kkkk He is supposed to know if the file is not inside the bundle. There is nothing to be displayed to the user.

Comment: maybe "please contact the developer, he/she forgot to include a file", haha

Comment: kkk Thats exactly what I mean. Fatal error is desired on those circumstances. You don't want to release the app without adding the file to the bundle.